# Setting up a bind forwarder, except for a domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, forwarding

I'm trying to setup a local bind DNS server (first time dealing with DNS servers, know a bit about records) that:

- Routes *.internal, *.*.internal to itself (preferably any combination of subdomains),
- Forwards everything else to a parent DNS server at 192.168.0.1

To start with, I'd like to tackle the second forwarding issue. The parent router/dns routes `hostname.Home` to a computer attached to the network, but these requests don't get forwarded on. Lookups for google.com and external sites do work however.

Currently I have the following named.conf:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    dnssec-validation no;
    dnssec-lookaside no;
    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035 

    listen-on { any; };
    listen-on-v6 { any; };

    # Recursively forward requests onto the parent DNS
    forwarders { 192.168.0.1; };
    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion { any; };
    allow-query { any; };
};
```

The results when I attempt to lookup domains:

**External domain, local dns**

```
ross@srv:~$ nslookup google.com 127.0.0.1
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.34.105
  ...snip...
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.34.104
```

**Internal domain, local dns**

```
ross@tigger:~$ nslookup ross-pc.home 127.0.0.1
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find ross-pc.home: NXDOMAIN
```

**Internal domain, parent dns**

```
ross@tigger:~$ nslookup ross-pc.home 192.168.0.1
Server:         192.168.0.1
Address:        192.168.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ross-pc.home
Address: 192.168.0.14
```

Bind error log:

```
named[6947]: DNS format error from 192.168.0.1#53 resolving ross-pc.home/A for
             client 127.0.0.1#50667: reply has no answer
named[6947]: error (FORMERR) resolving 'ross-pc.home/A/IN': 192.168.0.1#53
named[6947]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'ross-pc.home/A/IN':
             2001:503:c27::2:30#53
named[6947]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'ross-pc.home/A/IN': 
             2001:500:3::42#53
```

I've tried to configure bind to be as unrestrictive as possible while I'm getting the basics working. Can someone explain why `*.Home` requests not being forwarded?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution - my upstream router is a home dsl-type router, which apparently can send large udp packets. [The solution described here](http://blog.kxr.me/2011/12/formerr-in-bind-9.html) was to add the following lines to use a different DNS mode between dns servers:

```
server ::/0 { edns no; };
server 0.0.0.0/0 { edns no; };
```

Comment: This is not the correct solution.  Either get a proper router (see RFC 5625 on how bad the DNS proxies inside home routers are)  or forward your queries to a real DNS server such as Google DNS or OpenDNS.